# What's the best Node.js mysql module for connecting to mysql over ssl?

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssl, node-mysql

I've built my app so far using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql). I just set up a securely accessible mysql database using AWS RDS service and have tested an SSL connection successfully with the mysql command line client. I have Amazon's public key .pem file. node-mysql doesn't seem to have an api for the SSL connect option.

The only one I've found so far is [Node-mysql-libmysqlclient](https://github.com/Sannis/node-mysql-libmysqlclient) but I got errors trying to connect with it, something about a bindings dependency being null so I'm not sure if I should trust it. Suggestions of which module/api to use? Alternatively, if you know what I need to modify in node-mysql I'd be willing to tinker a bit but it looks like it's using lower level Sockets to connect to MySQL so I'm not sure how hard it would be to get the SSL part added on.

Comment: FYI to connect with the command line mysql client all that's needed is, "mysql -h host -u username -ssl_ca=mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem -p" where mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem is a public key file provided by Amazon. I didn't need to generate any other keys or certificates.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Use Sequelize!  Hands down best ORM around for MariaDB/MySQL.
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize

```
npm install sequelize
--- then ---
npm install mariadb
--- or ---
npm install mysql
```

Comment: why all the downvotes without any comment as to why?

Answer (score 10):

```
var mysql  = require('mysql');
var fs     = require('fs');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db',
  ssl      : {
        ca   : fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server-ca.pem'), // should be enough for AWS
        key  : fs.readFileSync('./ssl/client-key.pem'), // required for google mysql cloud db
        cert : fs.readFileSync('./ssl/client-cert.pem'), // required for google mysql cloud db
  }
});
```

that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The node-mysql module supports ssl connections as showed here: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#ssl-options.